# Pass a pointers value by reference

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it possible to refer to the address value that the pointer variable holds.

For example, my function is `something(int &num);` and I need to pass a pointer to it, such as  `int* i = new int(1); like &(*(i));` Can this be done?

I am using qt and I don't know why but the following occurs...

- `*&ui->numberInput->text()` gives a `QString`
- `&ui->numberInput->text()` gives a `*QString`
- `*ui->numberOutput->text()` gives `*QLabel-text()`
- `ui->numberInput->text()` gives a `QString`

It wont be accepted as a `&QString`?

Could someone please help me with this problem

Comment: Alright, you need to clarify. You don't "pass references". If you want a reference, make the function take a reference. A reference to what? Your question code and text don't match. The code says a reference to an int, but your text says a reference to a pointer. Which is it?

Comment: @Gman, it appears Will uses the phrase "value of the pointer" to refer to the value the pointer *points to* instead of the more common meaning, which is to refer to the address value the pointer variable *holds*.

Comment: Will, your additional text suggests you have an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). In this case, X is that you're calling `ui->numberInput->text()`, which returns a `QString` value, and you want to pass the result to a function expecting a `QString&` parameter, but the compiler won't let you; and Y is that you managed to get a `QString*`, so maybe you can pass the pointed-to `QString` to that function expecting a reference. You should have *started* asking about X, because it has very little to do with what you *actually* asked about.

Comment: @Rob At first I thought the above was the problem.

Comment: Could you show more of the code? What exactly are you trying to do? I agree with Rob about the XY thing.

Answer (score 4):

you simply pass it like this

```
something(*i);
```

Comment: Exactly. You don't worry about whether it's a pass by reference or pass by value, the compiler handles that for you - the syntax from the caller's point of view is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> It wont be accepted as a &QString??

`&` serves a few different purposes in C++. In the declaration of a type it means "reference" while in usage with a variable it could be "address of". It's not entirely clear which you're trying to indicate here. Showing us what you're trying to pass and then the declaration of the function you're trying to pass it to might have been clearer.

That said, you mention `QLabel::text()` which returns a `QString`. If you want to pass the result of `text()` to a function taking a reference to a `QString` then you can just do so directly.

```
// Given a function with this declaration
void SomeFunction(const QString& parameter);
// and also this varable.
QLabel* l = new QLabel;

// Then the following call would work:
SomeFunction(l->text());
```

On the other hand, if this wasn't what you meant then show us the actual code you're having problems with and the error message that you're getting from it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The syntax is *&p.